# Slice with Projection with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way to implement a slice along with a projection in just one query using the c# driver?
Below is what i am trying to achieve using c#, but im stuck, can anyone help me out wit it?

```
db.employee.find({"employeeId": "999"}, { "empActivity" : { "$slice": -1 } }, {"employeeId": 1, "empActivity.transId": 1, _id: 0})
```

Note : empActivity is a an array containing nested documents, my query above works perfectly via the mongo shell but i am not able to figure out its equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this with the C# driver. Methods can be chanined on builders, so all of `.Slice()` and `.Include()`and `.Exclude()`

```
var fields = Fields.Slice("empActivity", -1)
    .Include("employeeId", "empActivity.transId")
    .Exclude("_id");

var cursor = collection.Find(query).SetFields(fields);
```