# How to access the first object within a nested BsonArray within a BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

As the title states I'm attempting to access the first object within a nested `BsonArray`. I'm new to mongodb so still trying wrap my head around it.

Anyways, lets say I have the following data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("111111dasd1asdasd1asd1"),
"data" : [ 
    {
        "name":"John Smith",
        "push ups":20
    },
    {
        "name":"John Smith",
        "push ups":22
    },
    {
        "name":"John Smith",
        "push ups":25
    }
]
}
```

I'm attempting to create a new `BsonDocument` by taking `_id` and `name` where I give the query a parameter for `_id` but I just grab whatever is in `name` without giving it a parameter.

ie.

```
{
  "connect":ObjectId("111111dasd1asdasd1asd1", //assigning the value of id from the original document to this field
  "name":"John Smith"
}
```

Since my mongo collection is structured so that each `Bsondocument` only deals with one unique `name`, I do not want to loop through the `data` `BsonArray` of my original document example. I just want to access whatever value `name` has and move on.

Here is my current code attempting to create a new object from values of `id` and `name` from the `BsonDocument`

(NOTE: This is within a method where an id param is provided).

```
 var query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
 var tempRecord = existing.FindOne(query);
 var record = new
     {
       name = tempRecord["data"]["name"],
       connect = id
     };
 result = record.ToBsonDocument();

 return result;
```

At the moment `tempRecord` is correctly storing the data returned from the query I'm passing it. However how would I properly access the `name` field of the `data` array within `tempRecord`?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27858346/5919473) and implement projection with slice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slice with Projection with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858247/slice-with-projection-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve each name of the same _id, here's the code, if you want to change it a little bit, just leave a comment :

first of all,you should change your _id value,it's invalid, put for example : ObjectId("56d18c7e5e4b3c416e7b408b")

database => test | collection => myCollection

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myCollection");
            var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId("56d18c7e5e4b3c416e7b408b"));
            using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter1))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (var document in batch)
                    {
                        int subDocMax = document[1].AsBsonArray.Count;
                        for(int i=0;i<subDocMax;i++)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Name :"+document[1][i][0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: My data was not real and was just for example's sake.

Comment: can you clarify more, please.